# How to validate the date input to prevent past date using Reactive forms in Angular?

Tags: angular

I need to validate date input in the form controls.

```
<input type="text" bsDatepicker>

<button [disabled="dateForm.invalid"> submit </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom validador to check the date. It would be something like:

```
export function dateValidator(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const isDateValid = //check the date here wherever you like
    return isDateValid ? null : { invalidDate: control.value };
}
```

And than you add It on your validators declaration of form:

```
public dateForm = new FormGroup({
    date: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, dateValidator]),  
})
```

The object with invalidDate is just an arbitrary name, it's an error object that you could place the name you want. Here is the reference for the oficial docs to create custom validators:
https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom validator function in your typescript file:

```
dateValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
    if (control?.value) {
        const today = new Date();
        const dateToCheck = new Date(control.value);
        if (dateToCheck < today) {
            return {'Invalid date': true}
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then use that validator function in your form-setup:

```
public dateForm = new FormGroup({
    date: new FormControl(null, [this.dateValidator]),  
})
```

Comment: This is work but i have one error only. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322). In return { 'Invalid date' ... }

Comment: I've edited my answer, check if it works now?

Comment: Work. But one more question. How to implement this function on ngModel form ?

Comment: Then I would suggest creating a validation-directive:
https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/a-practical-guide-to-angular-template-driven-forms#validators

Using the code in the above dateValidator inside the 'validator'-function in the directive.